# Multiple-step OLE DB error on connection to Access2000

Tags: ms-access, iis-7, asp-classic, database-connection, connection-string

I have a classic ASP application. It connects to Access 2000 database.

The provider: *Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0*
The OS: *Windows Server 2008 with IIS7*
In IIS7, ASP module has been installed.

The connectionString used is:

```vbscript
public_path = "C:\database\"
RealPath = public_path & "dbname.mdb"
ConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & RealPath  & "; Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" & Password
```

If the `*.mdb` file is Read-Only then I can open connection and read data, but I get errors on insert or update.

If the `*.mdb` file is Read&Write then on `conn.open()` I get the following error:

> -2147217887 Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.

I have read [this support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269495) and verified the key *OLEDB_SERVICES* exists in the system registry.

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

Comment: Your connection string is little weird; if you try just `ConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & RealPath` does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the permission of the users.
The group "USERS" have to have "Deny Write" on the main website folder.
The group "USERS" have to have "Full Control" on the database folder and file.